# Print all days from beginning of year till last

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures, printing, sql-date-functions

My below code doesnot execute properly .
please help me where i went wrong to print.

```
alter procedure dbo.display
as
begin
declare @start date
declare @end date


set @start=DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()),0)
set @end =DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())+1,-1)

while(@start>@end)
begin
select @start
end
set @start=DATEADD(DD,1,@start)
end
```

Comment: I think you should move the line `end` forward 2 lines, and change this line `while @start < @end`

Comment: DATEADD statement should be inside the while loop

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: ya correct Abdul thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code, with:

- the `while` condition (should be `<`, not `>`)
- the `set` outside the loop.

Try the following code:

```
declare @start date
declare @end date

set @start = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
set @end = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) 

while(@start <= @end)
begin
    print @start
    set @start = DATEADD(DD,1,@start)
end
```

Enjoy!